Необходимо собрать ffprobe без ffmpeg, чтобы не тащить не нужные зависимости
Дали задачу на практике в универе. Нужно собрать из исходников ffmpeg'а
ffprobe, чтобы он встал один без ffmpeg. Я знаю что есть статичный бинарник ffprobe, он не подходит к работе на debian 12 из-за ошибки Segmentation Fault. (скорее всего ошибка из-за версии gcc)
Бинарник надо собрать без программ типа ELF Statifier.
Коротко: нужно каким то образом поставить только ffprobe из исходников ffmpeg без лишних зависимостей и чтобы встало на debian 12.

Бинарник надо собрать руками без посторонних программ - крутая задача. вот прямо надо писать руками инструкции процессора в файл? никаких трансляторов-ассемблеров-линковщиков?

нет имеется ввиду собрать стандартными средствами, извините я не сильно разбираюсь в этом.

Как правило, у больших проектов всегда есть какие-то иструкции по сборке, FFmpeg - не исключение. Переходим в репозиторий и смотрим в файл INSTALL.md. Оттуда нас посылают в ./configure --help, где среди флагов находим:
Program options:
  --disable-programs       do not build command line programs
  --disable-ffmpeg         disable ffmpeg build
  --disable-ffplay         disable ffplay build
  --disable-ffprobe        disable ffprobe build

Как раз то, что нам нужно! Запускаем скрипт, отключая сборку ненужных програм (по подсказке скрипта мне пришлось добавить --disable-x86asm):
./configure --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-x86asm

После сборки
make

проверям, что ffprobe собрался:
ls -la ffprobe

и запускается
./ffprobe --help


Ещё один глупый вопрос. Как потом собранный бинарник ffprobe перетащить в другую систему и использовать? Возможно ли это вообще? Или нужно будет какое-то другое ПО, чтобы собрать зависимости? Если кратко, то нужно, чтобы бинарник ffprobe работал без дополнительной установки других завимостей.  Желательно надо пихнуть всё в бинарник сразу.
